# Cannot UPDATE even IF NOT EXISTS doesn't return rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, exists

Can anyone tel me whats wrong with this SQL statement please?

```
const string updateStatement = " IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM BankAccount WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber AND deleted IS NULL) " +
                             " UPDATE BankAccount SET BankAccount.deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber";
```

Here I'm trying to recover a deleted bank account record (a logically deleted one). Even the `IF NOT EXISTS()` part doesn't return any records `UPDATE` is not happened!

**Table**

```
BankAccount [ac_no(pk), emp_id, ac_name, bank_name, emp_name, status, deleted]
```

**EDIT:**

Before recovering a bank account the system should check whether there are any other bank account entered for that employee. If there is another bank account for the same employee the recovery should not happened as at any given time an employee should have only one bank account.

[image]

Comment: how about showing us some data as well

Comment: I think your logic is wrong, you should check `IF EXISTS .. deleted IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You don't need to check for Account number as the requirement is to check on emp_id. So do check on Emp_Id and then only update the account of that employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to check that the employee holding the account doesn't have any other open accounts.

Below, BA1 contains just the account we might undelete. BA2 contains all the employee's open accounts. If the employee has no open accounts, the select won't return anything.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BankAccount BA1 INNER JOIN BankAccount BA2 ON BA1.ac_no = @ACNumber AND BA1.emp_id = BA2.emp_id AND BA2.deleted IS NULL)
    UPDATE BankAccount SET Deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber
```

In your original statement, you're only checking that single account row, and you're not looking at other accounts the employee may have or may have had. If you know the employee ID as well as the account number when running the statement, you could simplify it to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BankAccount WHERE emp_id = @EmployeeId AND Deleted IS NULL)
    UPDATE BankAccount SET Deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber
```

**EDIT**

I don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @BankAccount TABLE ([ac_no] int
                           ,[emp_id] int
                           ,[name] varchar(50)
                           ,deleted datetime
                           )

INSERT @BankAccount VALUES (17, 103, 'GS Siri', NULL)
                         , (18, 108, 'N.S Per', '2014-08-10')
                         , (19, 116, 'K.V Sil', NULL)
                         , (25, 104, 'N.Kusha', NULL)
                         , (45, 108, 'N.S Per', '2014-08-11')

SELECT * FROM @BankAccount

DECLARE @ACNumber int
SET @ACNumber = 45

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @BankAccount BA1 INNER JOIN @BankAccount BA2 ON BA1.ac_no = @ACNumber AND BA1.emp_id = BA2.emp_id AND BA2.deleted IS NULL)
    UPDATE @BankAccount SET Deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber

SELECT * FROM @BankAccount
```

The first select shows the following:

```
ac_no  emp_id  name     deleted
17     103     GS Siri  NULL
18     108     N.S Per  2014-08-10 00:00:00.000
19     116     K.V Sil  NULL
25     104     N.Kusha  NULL
45     108     N.S Per  2014-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

The second:

```
ac_no  emp_id  name     deleted
17     103     GS Siri  NULL
18     108     N.S Per  2014-08-10 00:00:00.000
19     116     K.V Sil  NULL
25     104     N.Kusha  NULL
45     108     N.S Per  NULL
```

If you can provide an example like I have above where it doesn't work, I can look into it further.

Comment: You got the point right. But the `sql` code doesn't work for me!

Comment: @Chathuranga - where does it go wrong? Does it give any errors?

Comment: No errors. But UPDATE didn't happen. With regard to second answer, actually I don't have employeeID. :(

Comment: @Chathuranga - see update. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: Now it works in SQL ;). I wonder why it didn't work for me in application (C#) still I'm working on it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR SUPPORT!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   BankAccount AS A 
           WHERE  A.ac_no = @ACNumber 
                  AND A.deleted IS NOT NULL
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                  FROM   BankAccount AS B 
                                  WHERE  B.Emp_id = A.Emp_id
                                         AND B.ac_no <> @ACNumber
                                         AND B.deleted IS NULL))
   UPDATE BankAccount
   SET    deleted = NULL
   WHERE  ac_no = @ACNumber AND deleted IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Actually this is not what I want. Please see the EDIT:

Comment: No luck. It didnt work. Actually I want to check whether there are any other bank account (not deleted) for this employee (the one  holding the bank account that is going to be recovered) before recovering!

Comment: This also doesn't work :(. It doesn't update deleted field to NULL even there is no any other active bank accounts for this employee

Comment: Now it works on SQL. I have something wrong in my app. Apologize for the mistake. Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below

```
const string updateStatement = 
"IF ((SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM BankAccount WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber AND deleted IS NULL)=1)"
+ 
"UPDATE BankAccount SET BankAccount.deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber";
```

Let me know if it worked for you ?

Comment: No luck. It doesn't update even there is no any other employees with the bank account which is going to be recovered!

Comment: Try using the same Query in SQL. I think the problem is with data. I have personally tested a similar Query on my local DB,

Answer (score 1):

try using this and tell us about it's result :

```
const string updateStatement =
      "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM BankAccount WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber AND ISNULL(CAST(deleted AS VARCHAR(20)),'0') = '0' ) " +
          "UPDATE BankAccount SET BankAccount.deleted = NULL WHERE ac_no = @ACNumber";
```

Comment: Excuse me,`IS_NULL` replaced with `ISNULL` and it will check the column, if it was null replace it's value by 0 to check condition

Comment: deleted is a DateTime field. When you delete a record it just hold the date and time deleted. If it's null means the record is active.

Comment: I know this, but sometimes when you check field IS NULL return false because the field appears as empty, are you checked my query ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are checking whether there are any other bank account entered for that employee, but your query is wrong because `ac_no` is `PK field` and your `IF` statement does not return correct value.

you should to change your query and replace `ac_no` with `emp_id` and looking over it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT *
       FROM   BankAccount
       WHERE  emp_id = @EmpID
              AND DELETED IS NULL
   )
    UPDATE BankAccount
    SET    BankAccount.deleted = NULL
    WHERE  emp_id = @EmpID
```

Comment: I up voted both your answers as I had to accept the answer of @Alex Humphrey as I realized my mistake from that answer. Appologize for my mistake. Thanks again ;)